# Javascript declaring number in different ways?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1;
var b = Number(1);
var c = new Number(1);
```

I was wondering what is the difference between these three statements.
I understand that first and second statements are same, as `if(a===b)` gives `true`, but the **third one will create a object** of type number.

What I want to know is how these methods are different, and any advantages one will give over the other?

Comment: If you could provide some context for your question it might help get you some better answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A value like `1` is a primitive, not an object. JavaScript will generally promote numbers to `Number` objects when necessary.  There's rarely a reason to explicitly construct one, and there's certainly no particular "advantage". There's also no reason for something like `Number(1)`, though the `Number` constructor is one of several ways of coercing a value to be a number.

Comment: @zzzzBov well they might be inside the VM, but they're not Object instances as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: @zzzzBov No, they arent. `typeof {}` => "object", but `typeof 123` => "number". You cannot add properties to a primitive value, but you can add them to a `Number` instance.

Comment: @zzzzBov things like `"hello".length` work because JavaScript does the boxing implicitly.

Comment: @lanzz, so by that (fallacious) argument, functions are not objects either as `typeof function(){} === "function"`.

Comment: They are called "Primitives" because they're primitive (simple) objects.

Comment: @zzzzBov see the spec, sections 4.3.2 and 4.3.3. If you want to call them objects or think of them that way, it's fine by me, but formally they're distinct from objects.

Comment: They are _not_ objects in OO sense (as demonstrated, they don't have properties). You might, if you like, call them "objects" in some other, non-OO sense of the word.

Comment: @lanzz, They're *primitive objects* because they don't have properties, but they're still a type of object. I think we're just getting into a debate on semantics here.

Comment: @zzzzBov They are not objects in _any_ meaningful OO-related sense of the word "object". `1 instanceof Object` is also false; as established, they have no properties and they cannot be used as prototypes to other objects. They are _not objects_ in _any object usage_ that is allowed in Javascript.

Comment: @lanzz: I agree with you that they're constants and not objects, but it is important to note that they are linked to their respective prototype chains (Number.prototype and String.prototype) so they are, at some level, still subject to the changes to the prototypes

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem no, they're not linked to the prototypes. The language implicitly boxes primitives in their object "partner" types when necessary.

Comment: @Pointy: I thought so, I'll edit my answer, but I wasn't 100% on that. Is it fair to say that JS wraps constant operands in an instance of its object counterpart, when the statement requires it?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes - if you check the spec, section 11.2.1, you can see how the property accessor (`.` and `[ ]`) is defined. In short, a call is made to the internal `toObject` function (section 9.9) which does the work.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Example of "not usable as prototype": `var a = 123; var b = {}; b.prototype = a;` Now, if the primitive value `123` was usable as an object, you could use its methods on the `b` instance via prototype inheritance; still, `b.toFixed()` throws "no such method" error, even though `b.prototype.toFixed` is "defined" (although it is only an illusion).

Comment: @lanzz, That's why I updated my answer to _JS wraps constant operands in an instance of its object counterpart, when the statement requires it_, I never said constants were objects, I merely remarked on their behaving similarly in certain situations (assignment not being one of them). Perhaps a topic for the ECMA mailing list: IMO, `b.prototype = a` should throw a type error

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That's why I explicitly avoided using a _constant_ as a prototype in my example. `b.prototype = a` won't throw a type error, because the `prototype` property is not magical in itself.

Answer (score 2):

In short, non: the `new String()` and `new Number()` constructors are to be ignored if you want to save yourself a world of trouble. 
The first two methods you present here assign a numeric constant to the variable, the third way -as you say- creates an object. The value of that object will be `1`, but you can change that value without loosing any specific methods you set to the object.

There aren't very many advantages to storing numbers or strings in objects. AFAIK, the only thing you *"gain"* is a very, very, very slight performance difference over the constants when invoking certain methods, like `toExponential` etc... 
In my view, that isn't worth the trouble of creating objects for all numbers you're bound to use. I think of it as one of the *bad parts* of JS, meant to make the language look familiar to Java Applet developers.

The second, without the new keyword, allows you to sort-of-type-cast: `Number(document.getElementById('formElem').value) === 123;` and has its uses (mainly with Date objects, in my experience). But then again, converting to a number can be achieved using the `+` operator, too: `+document.getElementById('formElem').value) === 123`

On the whole, just stay well clear of these primitive constructors. The only reason they're still there is because they're objects, and therefore have prototypes. Now **THAT** is an advantage:

```
Number.prototype.addOneToString = function()
{
    return (1+this).toString();
};
String.prototype.UpperFirst = function()
{
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
var foo = new Number(3);
foo.addOneToString();//returns "4"
foo = new String('foo');
foo.UpperFirst();//Foo
```

Since JS wraps constant operands in an instance of its object counterpart, when the statement requires it, you can apply prototype methods (either native or self-made ones) to any constant. (Thanks to Pointy for this, and +1)

```
(3).addOneToString();//"4"
'foo'.UpperFirst();//Foo
```

So just regard them as legacy quirks, that are still there because of their prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

In ES12 and after you can use the below ways to declare large numbers.

```
const oneMillion = 1_000_000;

var oneMillion1 = 1_000_000;
```

you can use separators `_`, for bitter readability