# Correct way to use numbers in Node.js

Tags: javascript

I am using node.js and while playing with command line, I can create number in following two ways :-

The simple way

```
> a = 1
1
```

and using `Number` class:-

```
> b = new Number(1)
[Number: 1]
```

When I check types of these variables it shows :-

```
> typeof a
'number'
> typeof b
'object'
```

When I check equivalence :-

```
> a == b
true
> a === b
false
```

`b` is instance of `Number` class, b is not.

```
> a instanceof Number
false
> b instanceof Number
true
```

My question `a` is instance of which class? What are the pros and cons of using numbers in different ways from testing and correctness of program perspective and which way should be followed?

Comment: Take a look at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355063/javascript-declaring-number-in-different-ways

Comment: `a` is not an instance of anything, since it is a primitive value and not an object.

Comment: @Amadan technically it's an instance of the number type. It's not an object but that doesn't mean it can't be an instance of a type :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Nitpick; you just need more cowb... more backticks. Okay, `a` is not an `instanceof` anything, since it is a primitive value and not an object (given that things are `instanceof` other things if they have those other things in their prototype chains, which non-object values lack).

Comment: @Amadan it's not an `instanceof` anything with the instanceof operator. However in spec language being "an instance of a typed" is defined differently than the instanceof operator (which is broken for several other reasons by the way). Number is most certainly a type (one of 6 primitive value types - number string boolean undefined null and symbol).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Oh, sure, `instanceof` is totally broken, I agree. I also agree that the word "instance" can be applied to types when not in OOP context (where it is firmly connected with objects). But it is `instanceof` that is mentioned in the question, and the distinction between non-objects and objects being preeminent, and answering the question out of that context makes no sense.